# Parts of Shabbos prayers sung out loud

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, song-poetry, shabbat-songs

Many synagogues sing Kel Odon and Mimkomcho on Shabbos morning. Why are these two the most commonly sung parts of the Shabbos morning Tefila?

Answer (score 3):

Kel Odon is a פיוט (liturgical hymn) and hence would seem to be *designed* to be sung. This in line with other פיוטים that we sing - such as those in the High Holiday Prayers and the Zmiros on Shabbos.

As far as Mikomcha - I think that caught on mostly due to the catchy tunes associated with it. It is much less common to find a Chasidish minyanim that sing Mimkomcha (as they tent to shy away from "modern" tunes durring prayer), however in the Yeshivish/Modern world it is very common (S. Carlbach's influence perhaps?), (although there are plenty Chasidish places that do as well).

Comment: I don't know about that last point. In many old-line Chabad shuls where I've davened, they've sung Mimkomcha to the tune of one or another chassidic niggun (often Lechatchila Ariber or Shamil).

Comment: @Alex thanks. I updated the post to reflect that there, indeed, are may Chasidish places (besides Chabad) that do sing.